# Making hair for the first time

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, hair

So I just started using blender recently, so I'm not that knowledgeable in this area. I've been doing simple characthers to get used to the tools and modifiers, and I wanted to try modeling some little creatures from one of my favortie mangas.

[image]

So I used the particle system to create the eyebrows, making a model for the hair and using the object mode in the particle system.
[image]

But as you can see, it's not giving a good result :s. I used a simple plane as the base for the particle system and mirrowed it, and I checked the use modifier stack box in the particle system, but I cant get a good result no matter how I tweak the options. Any advice?

Comment: Hi Juan - I tried recreate the effect you are looking for, and using the Hair mode of the particle system with interpolated children and some combing seems to work - have you tried that?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I just moved on from that proyect, but i tried my luck yesterday after watching some tutorials and I got some pretty good results.